# input attribute for mobile number where user can not type non-numeric data on all devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, input

I don't need all this below for input:

```
<input type="number"/>
<input type="tel"/>
```

The above inputs are right but I need input attribute where user even can't type non-numeric data.

Comment: So, where do you want people to do?

Comment: just type only number other than that should not even be typed.

Comment: What's wrong with `<input type="number">` exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no HTML tag to allow the only number but you can do the same thing using JavaScript.

```js
// Allow only number character while pasting the content
function isPasteNumber(eventParam, inputField){
 eventParam.preventDefault();
 
 var clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
 if(!isNaN(clipboardData.getData('Text'))){
  inputField.value = parseInt(clipboardData.getData('Text'));
 }
}

// Allow only number character
function isNumber(eventParam) {
 eventParam = (event) ? eventParam : window.event;
 var charCode = (eventParam.which) ? eventParam.which : eventParam.keyCode;
 
 if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Number only" onkeypress=" return isNumber(event);" onpaste="isPasteNumber(event, this);" />
```

This will help you.